# How do you configure GCC in Eclipse to use C99?

Tags: eclipse, gcc, c99

I'm working on a small C project in Eclipse; I just installed Eclipse from the Ubuntu Software Center and added C/C++ Language Support. I can build, run, and debug simple C programs fine.

But I'm using some C99 features now, and Eclipse complains, saying "'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode".

I thought you'd set C99 mode for GCC in the makefile, but the makefile is auto-generated by Eclipse so any changes I make would be overwritten, but I don't see anywhere to put GCC compiler options anywhere in Eclipse's preferences nor my Project Properties windows.

So where do I define C99 mode?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Go into project properties. Search for C/C++Build -> Settings. In the Tool Settings tab search for GCC C compiler and then Miscellaneous. In other flags text box add the -std=c99. It should work fine.

Comment: @Beppe.. Thanks! It helped a lot and saved me precious time. Cheers!

Comment: You can now go to the `Dialect` folder instead and select c99 from the dropdown.

Comment: Just read this answer - is there a way to enable this misc. flag by default as opposed to re-doing it for every single C project? Thanks!

Comment: @Tobber There is not option for C89 there.